# Removing duplicates from the services resolved by avahi-client

Tags: c, gtk, mdns, zeroconf, avahi

I want to use the C avahi library to create a dialog box in gtk that can list all the services in DNS-SD network. I am able to list all the services in a dialog box but I want to **clean this list of duplicate entries**. [image: output for avahi-browse]As you can see in the image above that that output of `avahi-browse -a` in my terminal gives me a lot of duplicates of the same service but from different interfaces( and hence different addresses ). I want to remove these duplicates.

Therefore to achieve this I used a **hash-table** to store the previously found services and only add a new service if the string concatenation of *name, port, type, domain, host_name* has never been added before. The code for which is roughly as shown below.
[image]

*Note*- I did not include the parameter *address*  and that is what I am curious about.

The end goal for me is to remove duplicates from different interfaces and protocols as on resolving we can see that these duplicates services have different addresses.
[image]

Will I be excluding unique services if I don't consider the *address* parameter?

Comment: Please do not post code and text logs as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: @kaylum Okay, I won't, just bare with me this time as I don't have the same setup up right now.